# django bulk user import user django-import-export

Tags: django, django-import-export

i want use import export to bulk user import in django

i get a file include list of users then create users according to file rows

i try implement before_import like this

```
from import_export import resources
class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    def before_import(self,dataset, dry_run, **kwargs):
        #dataset is  tablib.Dataset()
        for i in dataset:
            i[1]=make_password(i[1])
        return super(UserResource, self).before_import(dataset, dry_run, **kwargs)
```

but it return tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: what si UserResource? what is dataset?

Comment: UserResource is import-export Resource ,see question update

Comment: that still leaves "what is dataset?" Also it would be a lot easier if you could tell us what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: question updated,dataset is  tablib.Dataset()

Answer (score 1):

For Passwords you could write your own password [widget](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_widgets.html#widgets), which turns the plain password into a hash. Like this (untested):

```
class PassWidget(Widget):
    def clean(self, value):
        if self.is_empty(value):
            return None
        return make_password(value)
    def render(self, value):
        return force_text(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to hash your password before importing.
it helps you:

```
    from import_export import resources, fields
    from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
    from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

    class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):

       groups = fields.Field(
           column_name='group_name',
           attribute='groups',
           widget=ManyToManyWidget(Group, ',','name')
       )
       def before_import_row(self,row, **kwargs):
           value = row['password']
           row['password'] = make_password(value)
       class Meta:
           model = User
```